# No permission for EXECUTE ACCESS TO PROCEDURE in Firebird DB

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

I followed the specs from the [manual](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-security-granting.html):

1. I created a role: `CREATE ROLE reader;`.
2. The user was created: `CREATE USER voron PASSWORD 'somepassword'`.
3. Then for to give permissions I did the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON exportit TO PROCEDURE sp_get_itexport_tags;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE sp_get_itexport_tags TO ROLE reader;
GRANT reader TO USER voron;
```

I also tried 'granting' to `PUBLIC` user, but it gives me the following error: `no permission to EXECUTE access to PROCEDURE sp_get_itexport_tags. Effective user is VORON`. I gave those permissions as `SYSDBA`. Logged on using role `reader` and user's password. What's wrong?

Comment: Exactly how did you login, and how did you specify the role, and did you verify that you really have the role (e.g. `select CURRENT_ROLE from RDB$DATABASE`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm am unable to reproduce (using ISQL against Firebird 4.0.4):

```sql
create database 'e:\db\fb4\check_rights.fdb' user sysdba;
create role reader;
set term #;
create procedure test_1 as begin end#
set term ;#
grant execute on procedure test_1 to role reader;
grant reader to user voron;
commit;
```

And then without the role:

```sql
connect 'e:\db\fb4\check_rights.fdb' user voron;
execute procedure test_1;
```

This will (as expected) result in error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
no permission for EXECUTE access to PROCEDURE TEST_1
-Effective user is VORON
```

With role, the procedure executes just fine:

```sql
connect 'e:\db\fb4\check_rights.fdb' user voron role reader;
execute procedure test_1;
```

This reports no error (the procedure does nothing useful, so there is no output).

My guess is that you didn't specify the role, or you specified the role in double quotes, so it becomes case-sensitive (in that case, `select CURRENT_ROLE from RDB$DATABASE` reports `NONE` instead of `READER`). Alternatively, you didn't commit your grant statements, or, because you're missing the procedure name in the grant shown in the question, you received an error which you ignored, and there is no actual permission granted.

You can also check which privileges have been granted:

```sql
select RDB$USER, RDB$RELATION_NAME, RDB$PRIVILEGE 
from RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES 
where RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'TEST_1' and RDB$OBJECT_TYPE = 5
```

Replace `TEST_1` with the actual procedure name. This should report privilege `X` (eXecute) granted to `READER`.

To check if the role has been granted, use

```sql
select RDB$USER, RDB$RELATION_NAME, RDB$PRIVILEGE 
from RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES 
where RDB$USER = 'VORON'
```

This should report "relation" `READER` and privilege `M` (Member).

Comment: You are right about my having made typo in the post. I haven't got any error and I also committed the transaction. Code samples approved that all permission are set. When I tried to select `CURRENT_ROLE`, I got `NONE`.  In connection settings window I look at a role input field. The roles's name was uppercased. But than I realised that it was a misleading action of `'Capitalize database object names'` flag. As soon as I unchecked that checkbox, my procedures worked as planned (the real role name entered was in lower case).

Comment: The only thing I want to add is how to set reader to be a default role for anybody? Once you wrote about default roles for logged on users. `GRANT READER TO USER PUBLIC;` according to specks gives nothing. Did you mean exactly this setting? By the way, it works only if you use `READER` explicitly when connecting as mentioned here: https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/7178

Comment: That statement doesn't grant a default role, it just grants the role. To grant a default role, you need to use `grant default READER to user PUBLIC`, but default roles aren't shown by `CURRENT_ROLE` (that only shows the explicitly specified role), you need to use `select RDB$ROLE_IN_USE('READER') from RDB$DATABASE` to check if a default role is active (or see [`RDB$ROLE_IN_USE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#newHashMap(int)) for an example to list all active roles).

Comment: Much obliged for the fast feedback.

Comment: Also, to be clear, default roles can also be granted to real users (and roles), not just PUBLIC.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example? I thought, that PUBLIC means 'any user logged on'.  How to use this default setting to target all users and roles?

Comment: I already gave an example: `grant default READER to user PUBLIC` will grant READER as a default role to PUBLIC, and it will activate when any user logs in. Or you can use `grant default READER to user VORON` to only grant it to VORON.